# What's the difference between blocking and muting a player?

Tags: overwatch

In Overwatch, there are 3 options for dealing with toxic players. **Mute**, **Report**, and **Block**.

**Report** is pretty self explanatory, but what's the difference between **Mute** and **Block**?

[image]

Comment: No offense, but this seems rather trivial.  These options are pretty universal among online games.

Comment: @TimmyJim Fair point. I asked because I didn't know the answer myself before researching.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that anyone can look it up on the off chance they don't know what it is. Also when you click them for players the game even tells you what's occurred. It tells you "Communications with X blocked" etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mute** will keep you from hearing a player on voice chat or seeing what they type in-game.

**Block** will prevent a player from private messaging you or adding you on Battle.net/Xbox Live/PSN.

Comment: These same options exist on Xbox, but are not special to Overwatch.

Comment: @DCShannon Updated my answer to include Xbox Live and PSN